# Black Screen + white cursor: How to boot into recovery on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, boot, display

every article I have read gives advice ASSUMING that you have successfully managed to get into safe mode by mashing F8 or shift F8 -- BUT this does not work on Windows 8.1. Even MS says it does not work as the boot process is too fast.

So - I have a recovery disk - but no way of telling the bios to recover from the USB or optical.

Question: How do I get into safe mode when F8 does not work ?

Many thanks - I've spent a day pulling my hair out on this so far !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this issue, press the power button to [force a shutdown. Repeat this 3 times and Windows will show the repair options](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Finding-Win8-Key-UI-Hang-in-Games-Modern-App-Update-Log#time=13m43s).

Comment: HI - Thanks for this suggestion. I've given it a try, so far without luck - there must be something I am doing wrong. After I have forced the shut down, I hit power on button. Question: do I let the PC power right up ? If not - how much time should I leave between power cycles ? I let it go approx. 5 seconds between cycles. Wrong technique ?? 

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

to enable <kbd>f8</kbd> for safe mode on windows 8 and later, issue this command as administrator:

```
bcdedit /set bootmenupolicy legacy
```

Comment: also, there is `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes` command to display boot menu without key pressing every time computer boots up

Comment: Thanks for this - I will enable this once I manage to get in.

Comment: why you have no way to access bios and try to change the boot order from its settings?

Comment: The whole point about the "black screen of death" is you can't see what is going on AND because Windows 8 has removed F8 safemode, you now have a pc which is unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Replacing Windows.UI.Immersive.dll file

Step 1 : go to system32 subfolder in Windows folder (typically C:\Windows\System32)

Step 2 : Find the Windows.UI.Immersive.dll,check for Date Created attribute(if it is in October 2012,you may have to replace with the recent one)

Step 3 : Goto WinSxS subfolder in Windows folder,search for Windows.UI.Immersive.dll(which is newer version) ](i found it in C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-windowsuiimmersive_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16408_none_c6ca1a15ef5e5709)

Step 4: Replace the older file with the newer one in system32 folder

Step 5: there is a hidden folder called Windows Activation Technologies in root drive(usually C:\Windows Activation Technologies),replace the older file in the above folder too.
Then restart,
hopefully this solves your problem

Source :Blank Screen after Installing Windows 8.1? - Microsoft Community
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/blank-screen-after-installing-windows-81/23fd21bb-4c37-4342-9b2c-5c9b396ed796?page=2